# How to get add SVN specific revision changes

Tags: svn

I have a issue.  Someone made changes awhile back and broke the code.  I managed to track the date when the code was broken.  Unfortunately, there were like 14 commits on that date.  Each commit had like a dozen files.  I like to start from the time where the code was good and incrementally add each commit to the good code until I find the commit that broke it.  This is what I had done so far.

> svn update -r {YYYY-MM-DD}    // got me to the good build
>
> svn update -r revisionNumber  // I don't think this is right because I am getting build error and each commit is supposed have clean build

How do I incrementally add each commit ?

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial and error, I found the solution.  Hopefully, this answer will help the next poor soul who has to look for other people problem.

> svn checkout yourBranchURL
>
> svn update -r {lastGoodDate}
>
> svn merge -c revisionNumber yourBranchURL // repeat this step until you hit the right revision